# Python 2.7 : global with imported modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, global

In Python 2.7, depending on how I import a module, global variables can become unreachable.

I have a file test.py which contains the following:

```
x = None

def f():
    global x
    x = "hello"
    print x
```

I get the following expected behavior:

```
>>> import test
>>> print test.x
None
>>> test.f()
hello
>>> print test.x
hello
```

But now if i do an ugly 'import *' instead, i get the follwoing:

```
>>> from test import *
>>> print x
None
>>> f()
>>> print x
None
```

So variable x is no longer accessible.. Any clues ?

thanks,
y

Comment: a small mistake: after `from test import *` calling `f()` prints `hello`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from test import *` will do the equivalent of `x = test.x`.  If you change `test.x` later (which your call to `foo()` will do), it will not change the copy of x in your local namespace.